# .pop() affects two lists at the same time

Tags: python, list

I was trying to make programm that finds determinant of any given matrix and in the next bit of programm I was trying to find all minors

```
def deff(m,y=[]):
  #Here must be other parts of the programm
  #But I don't think they are affecting this bit
  x=0
  for i in range(len(m)): #m is the matrix(2d list)
    y=m[:][:]
    k=y[0][i] 
    y.pop(0) #removing first row
    for j in range(len(y)):
    y[j].pop(i) #removing column
    x+=k*deff(y)*(-1**(1+i)) 
  return x
```

And here comes the problem. When the programm does it's first **pop** *(y.pop(0))* it removes list only from **y**, but when it does it's second **pop** *(y[j].pop(i))* it removes numbers from **m** too. And I can't find the solution. I tried other ways of assignment *(as you can see in the programm, I was not using [:] but it didn't help)*, I tried to crating two seperate massives, other ways to delete numbers from list like delete and using other's ways to delete column, but no matter what I do it always deletes numbers from **m**

Comment: `def deff(m,y=[])` <= this is a mutable default argument (this note is not related to the question, but kind of sets the expectation for the rest of the code)

Comment: The second `[:]` in `y=m[:][:]`  makes a copy of a copy. Just `y = m.copy()`

Comment: finally, the answer: this is a shallow copy. `y` is a copy of references to actuall mutable arrays in `m`

Comment: .copy() doesn't work

Comment: Try

```
from copy import deepcopy

     y = deepcopy(m)
```

As @Marat mentioned, you also have a mutable argument in your definition ( https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/ ). Try changing your parameters to this:

```
def deff(m, y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = []
```